# Hiding a struct in c, why is this working?

Tags: data-structures, struct, types, hide, private

I wanted to hide a structure in C and after some failed attempts and some attempts which could lead to undefined behaviour, i found out this one is perfectly working: (from my stringlib.h file)

```
typedef struct
{
    #if defined(_STRINGLIB_OVERLOADING_WAIT_) || defined(_STRINGLIB_STRING_ACCESSIBLE_)
    //actual string
    char *getString;
    //string size in bytes
    size_t getSize;
    //string size in characters (=size in bytes-1)
    size_t getSizeChars;
    //should both point to _STRINGLIB_ALLOCATION_TRUE_ when string is allocated
    void *stringAllocation;
    void *stringSignature;

    #else
    uintptr_t:8*sizeof(void*);
    size_t:8*sizeof(size_t);
    size_t:8*sizeof(size_t);
    uintptr_t:8*sizeof(void*);
    uintptr_t:8*sizeof(void*);

    #endif // _STRINGLIB_OVERLOADING_WAIT_
}String;
```

This way the string is only accessible by the stringlib.c file (so can be modified only with the stringlib.h functions) and, having a given size, a new variable with type String can be declared anywhere, even inside a structure;

The funny part is: i have no idea why this is working, as i've never declared unnamed variables before and i wasn't even able to find something similiar on the internet, so i need some explanations;

By the way, i found no way to actually use a pointer instead of uintptr_t and this reduces the portability of my code (no C89), does anybody have workaround for it?

.

.

EXAMPLE main.c:

```
#include "stringlib.h"
int main()
{
    String mystring;
    //These (and other) functions are defined in stringlib.h
    string_append(&mystring, "hello");
    string_append(&mystring, " world");
    string_print(mystring);
    string_delete(&mystring);

    //THIS GIVES AN ERROR (as it is supposed to)
    mystring.getString;
    //SO DOES THIS
    mystring.getSize = 1;
    //As the mystring has no parameters despite having a given size when declared;
    //these parameters are however visible from stringlib.c file
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what this code is doing, but note that undefined behavior can sometimes show up as code which seems to be working perfectly. In any event -- it would help if you provide a `main` which *uses* this structure in a way that illustrates what it is supposed to do. Make a [mcve] that others can experiment with.

Comment: @JohnColeman i povided an example